# Does D distinguish between return/argument types of dynamic vs. static arrays?

Tags: arrays, d

Suppose I define a function, mutate, which replaces a random index's contents of an int array, `a`, with some function applied

```
int[] mutate(int[] a) {
    int randomIndex = cast(int) uniform(a[randomIndex]);
    a[randomIndex] = a[randomIndex] + 1;
    return a;
}
```

**Does this function specify input and return values of dynamic int array, static int array, or both?** That is, is this function limited to accepting and returning either subtype of array? Is there a way to distinguish between dynamic and static arrays as arguments to a function?

Do either of the following throw an error?

```
void main() {
    int[] dyn;
    dyn = [1, 2, 3];
    writeln(mutate(dyn));

    int[3] stat = [1,2,3];
    writeln(mutate(stat));
}
```

Comment: "Do either of the following throw an error?" you can always try it yourself!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> int[] mutate(int[] a)
> ```

That takes a slice and returns a slice. A slice is not necessarily a dynamic array, it might be a static array, though then you need to pass it as `stat[]` instead of just `stat`.

A slice is like a `ptr` and `length` combo in C: a pointer to data (which may reside anywhere, a dynamic array, a malloc array, a static array, some block of memory, whatever) and a count of the length.

When you return one like that, you do need to be kinda careful not to store it. The slice doesn't know where it is stored and you might easily lose track of who owns it and end up using a bad pointer! So be sure the scope is safe when doing something like this.

Read this for more info:

http://dlang.org/d-array-article.html

Comment: do you mind clarifying the syntax necessary for specifying the array as static in terms of the example? For example, something like `static int[] mutate(static int[] a)`.

Comment: I would point out that per the official spec and terminology, `T[]` is a dynamic array, not the block of memory that it refers to, and `T[]` is a dynamic array whether it's backed by GC-allocated memory, malloced memory, a static array, or any other kind of memory. If it's non-null, it is a slice of memory, but slice is not the official term for `T[]`. Dynamic array is. And since you can slice other types of objects and not get `T[]` (e.g. slicing a container usually results in range type specific to that container, not `T[]`), calling `T[]` a slice tends to cause other types of confusion.

Comment: @DavidShaked A static array is an array whose length is fixed at compile time and resides on the stack rather than referring to memory elsewhere. The keyword `static` is not involved. e.g. `int[5]` is a static array, whereas `int[]` is a dynamic array: http://dlang.org/spec/arrays.html#static-arrays

Comment: @JonathanMDavis The distinction between static and dynamic arrays is clear, but I was unsure if the syntax of declarations carried over.

Comment: @DavidShaked You can always tell a static array from a dynamic array by looking at the type declaration - though you don't know from looking at a dynamic array's type whether it's backed by a static array or GC memory or malloc-ed memory or whatever, since that's not part of the type system and could change over the lifetime of the dynamic array (e.g. appending to a dynamic array backed by anything but GC-allocated memory will result in a reallocation so that it's then backed by GC-allocated memory).

Comment: Thank you, @JonathanMDavis. I wasn't aware that the difference is transparent to the type system. Please correct me if my interpretation of your response goes too far.